# Factorization of linear ordinary differential operators

Tags: differential-equations, differential-operators

I was looking for references that give a detailed survey of techniques of factorization of linear ordinary differential operators. Specifically if there are references that do a complexity analysis of these techniques it would be extremely helpful. The same question was posted in math stack exchange with no answers:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464125/factorization-of-differential-operators